# Does adoCon.open in asp returns any value

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, ado

I am establishing a connection to a mssql server database in asp using the command

> adoCon.Open "Driver={SQL Server}; Server=" & host_name & "; Database="
>   & db_name & "; Uid=" & user_name & "; Pwd=" & password

Now my question is how to know if this connection establishment was successful. Does adoCon.open returns any value which I can use in my if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are useing ADODB-ActiveX object... so that would be the property `adoCon.State`.

> - adStateClosed      0  -> The object is closed
> - adStateOpen        1  -> The object is open
> - adStateConnecting  2  -> The object is connecting
> - adStateExecuting   4  -> The object is executing a command
> - adStateFetching    8  -> The rows of the object are being retrieved

find more information here [enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_ref_connection.asp)

Answer (score 0):

> After this method successfully completes, the connection is live and
>   you can issue commands against it and process the results.

So it returns when the connection is established; if for any reason it could not be created - invalid credentials, networking issue etc - it will raise an error which you should trap & deal with inline or in a helper routine.

```
function open(cn as adodb.connection) as boolean
on error goto handler
   cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server}; Server=" & host_name & "; Database=" & db_name & "; Uid=" & user_name & "; Pwd=" & password
   open=true
   exit function
handler:
    response.write "fail " & err.description
end function
```

Comment: Better to add a link to the documentation that you're quoting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676505%28VS.85%29.aspx